# Adding exceptions for some function from mangling with uglifyjs from command line

Tags: javascript, npm, uglifyjs

I am using uglifyjs to minimize and mangle a javascript file. I am using the following command

```
uglifyjs file.js -o file.min.js -c -m toplevel
```

I want to mangle the function names also, that's why I added *toplevel* as an option for *-m(mangle)* . However I want to add exceptions for some functions.
I looked at the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js#mangler-options
and gave the following command

```
uglifyjs file.js -o file.min.js -c -m toplevel -r 'fName1,fName2'
```

But that did not work and both the function names were still mangled. 
I am able to successfully add exception for a single function using the command

```
uglifyjs file.js -o file.min.js -c -m toplevel -r fName1
```

But I need a way to add exceptions for multiple functions.

Comment: Changing from single quotes to double quotes resolved it. I was using Windows (7) and command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, via *Command Prompt*, you need to wrap the exceptions in double quotes (`"`). For example:

`uglifyjs file.js -o file.min.js -c -m toplevel -r "fName1,fName2"`